# Load List Items dynamically with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to structure my JQuery to fade in each individual item at a time. Here's [an example of the behavior](http://satbulsara.com/tests/), and here's the JQuery I have so far:

```
$('li').css('display', 'none') .delay(1000).fadeIn(800)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var delay = 500, t = 0;
$("li").css('display', 'none').each(function(){
  t += delay;
  var $li = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $li.fadeIn();
  },t);
});
```

Comment: hmm this one seems to just hidfe the list

Comment: Sorry, just fixed it (and tested in your page). Using $(this) inside a setTimeout was not the best...

Answer (score 3):

This probably not the best solution but it should work:

```
$('li').each(function(i){
  var el = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(el).fadeIn(800);
  },800*i)
});
```

Just for fun, a recursive version:

```
function animateLi(i){
  $('li').eq(i).fadeIn(800);
  if ($('li').eq(i+1).length>0)
  {
      setTimeout(function(){animateLi(i+1)},800);
  }
}
animateLi(0);
```

Comment: Although, I just noticed that `this` will refer to `window` inside the `setTimeout`. You need to store it in a variable outside the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the li, and use setTimeout to queue the animation for that li.

```
$('li').each(function () {
    var li = this;
    animateLi = function () {
        li.fadeIn(800);
    }
    setTimeout(animateLi, timeout);
    timeout += 100;
});
```

Comment: i have this but i would like to do it in a cleverer way regardless of the amount of items

Comment: $('li').css('display', 'none').first().fadeIn(1900).next().delay(500).fadeIn(1900).next().delay(700).fadeIn(1900).next().delay(900).fadeIn(1900);

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation on Ivans method

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li:hidden').each(function(idx) {
        setTimeout(function(el) {
            el.fadeIn();
        }, idx* 1000, $(this));
    });
});
```

And a recursive function using fadeIn callback function instead of setTimeout

```
function DisplayOneByOne(){
    $('ul li:hidden:first').fadeIn('2000',  DisplayOneByOne);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it:

```
var delay = 200, t = 0;
$("li").css('display', 'none').each(function(){
    t += delay;
    var $li = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $li.fadeIn(1900);
    },t);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to fade in elements after each other:

```
$.fn.fadeInNext = function(delay) {
    return $(this).fadeIn(delay,function() {
        $(this).next().fadeInNext();
    });
};

$('li').hide().first().fadeInNext(1000);
```