# Loading List Items with JQuery dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load List Items dynamically with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932506/load-list-items-dynamically-with-jquery)

I have the following JQuery used to load list items:

```
$('li').css('display', 'none').first().fadeIn(1900).next().delay(500).fadeIn(1900).next().delay(700).fadeIn(1900).next().delay(900).fadeIn(1900);
```

I would like to load each list item 1 at a time with a delay like the above would like to do it in a cleaner way, so that I won't have to edit the JQuery to add more items to the list.

Example:  Here's the [JQuery in action](http://satbulsara.com/tests/).